# Converting .NET DateTime to JSON Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

My webs service is returning a DateTime to a jQuery call. The service returns the data in this format:

```
/Date(1486308595040)/
```

I am getting multiple data from table of database i have seen many articles on this and they answered this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1245398693390);
document.write(d);
```

But i have 1000 or more records from that answer i have to do get each row and convert it into json friendly data that is not a suitable.

My Code :

```
var history = db.v_recharge_payment_History.Where(x => x.RCV_UID == loginQuery.ID).OrderByDescending(x => x.RCV_ID).Take(10).ToArray();
                    dictionary.Add("result", 200);
                    dictionary.Add("data", history);
                    return Json(dictionary, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

How can I convert this into a JavaScript-friendly date without iterate each row ?

Comment: @quasoft, this answer saying that you have to convert each datetime columns of each row that is not possible if i have 10,000 or more records and thank you for your answer

Comment: What do you mean 1,000 rows? Your `.Take(10)` only returns 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the JavascriptSerializer to generate the JSON. the `Controller.Json()` method uses the built-in JavaScriptSerializer, which has many problems besides the weird date serialization. Instead, inherit JsonResult, and reimplement using Newtonsoft Json.NET. I won't give an example here because this is an old problem and you should be able to find plenty of examples on the web for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use  Newtonsoft JSON serializer and annotate your DateTime property with

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
```